# PHP null question?

Tags: php, null, pdo

I have this php statement in my login script...

```
else if ($_POST['email'] === $details['email'] &&
         $_POST['password'] === $details['password'] &&
         is_null($details['logcount'])) {
    echo 'Account not active!';
}
```

In my mysql table the logcount by default is NULL, when a user activates their account the logcount turns to 0 then increments every time they login.

On my login script I am having trouble with PHP testing it to see if it is NULL or not. I have pulled all the users data via an associative array using PDO.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Storing plain-text passwords in the database is bad. You should be hashing them at the very least.

Comment: you can set default to -1 and check if logcount < 0

Comment: Good idea, thanks Haim, I am testing Phil, just trying to get the mechanics working first! thanks.

Comment: @carlgcoder What does `var_dump($details['logcount'])` display? I only ask as `is_null()` returns true for `null` and `false` for `0` and `"0"` so your code should work as expected.

Comment: Try doing a `var_dump($details);` to see what's actually in there. While your at it, do a `var_dump($_POST)` to make sure that everything is as expected. You can also break down each of the three comparisons to see which one is failing.

Comment: var_dump($details['logcount']) returns - null

Comment: I just thought, php is displaying null, and the mysql is NULL, would this matter?

Comment: @carlgcoder No, it doesn't matter. I think your problem is elsewhere and not to do with the value in `logcount`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the isset() function.  If not, then you may have to tell PDO how to handle nulls for your db server.  Look at the accepted solution here:

[PHP PDO fetch null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2855961/php-pdo-fetch-null)

and setattribute docs here:

http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.setattribute.php

Comment: The problem lies somewhere else. is_null() is the right function to use for the purpose. If there's some way to tell PDO how to handle nulls, give an example of that.

Comment: @Doug See http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.setattribute.php however the default is to return nulls as `NULL`

Comment: Cool. Can you modify your answer with that info?

Comment: Ok, I edited this answer to be more descriptive.  I think result from isset() vs is_null() depends on how PDO is handling nulls.